# ESP32 (ESP-IDF) "driver/twai.h" CAN Data Transmission is working but Receive function is not working using CAN/TWAI

Tags: esp32, can-bus, esp-idf

I saw a YouTube video with someone who used a similar code, and it was working perfectly for him (YouTube Video: link: https://youtu.be/bxzWuIqfn9Y). He used "driver/can.h" which has been removed from v5.0 of ESP-IDF because CAN and TWAI are the same.

More details:
Issue raised on GitHub: https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/issues/10757#issue-1582253298
IDF version used: v5.0 and v4.4.4
Operating System used: Windows
IDE used to program and flash code: VS Code IDE

This is my code:

```
#include "driver/gpio.h"
#include "freertos/FreeRTOS.h"
#include "freertos/task.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "driver/twai.h"

void twai_setup_and_install(){
    //Initialize configuration structures using macro initializers
    twai_general_config_t g_config = {
        .mode = TWAI_MODE_NORMAL,
        .tx_io = GPIO_NUM_5,
        .rx_io = GPIO_NUM_4,
        .clkout_io = TWAI_IO_UNUSED,
        .bus_off_io = TWAI_IO_UNUSED,
        .tx_queue_len = 5,
        .rx_queue_len = 5,
        .alerts_enabled = TWAI_ALERT_NONE,
        .clkout_divider = 0
    };

    twai_timing_config_t t_config = TWAI_TIMING_CONFIG_500KBITS();
    twai_filter_config_t f_config = TWAI_FILTER_CONFIG_ACCEPT_ALL();

    // Install TWAI driver
    if (twai_driver_install(&g_config, &t_config, &f_config) == ESP_OK) {
        printf("Driver installed\n");
    } else {
        printf("Failed to install driver\n");
        return;
    }

    // Start TWAI driver
    if (twai_start() == ESP_OK) {
        printf("Driver started\n");
    } else {
        printf("Failed to start driver\n");
        return;
    }
}

void new_message(twai_message_t *message, uint32_t id, uint8_t dlc, uint8_t *data)
{
    
    message->flags = TWAI_MSG_FLAG_NONE;
    message->identifier = id;
    message->data_length_code = dlc;
    for (int i = 0; i < dlc; i++) {
        message->data[i] = data[i];
    }
    printf("Message created\nID: %ld DLC: %d Data:\t", message->identifier, message->data_length_code);
    for (int i = 0; i < message->data_length_code; i++) {
        printf("%d\t", message->data[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void transmit_message(twai_message_t *message)
{
    if (twai_transmit(message, pdMS_TO_TICKS(1000)) == ESP_OK) {
        printf("Message queued for transmission\n");
    } else {
        printf("Failed to send message\n");
    }
}

void receive_message(twai_message_t *message)
{
    if (twai_receive(message, pdMS_TO_TICKS(1000)) == ESP_OK) {
        printf("Message received:\n");
        printf("ID: %ld DLC: %d Data:\t", message->identifier, message->data_length_code);
        for (int i = 0; i < message->data_length_code; i++) {
            (message->extd)?printf("Extended ID"):printf("Standard ID");
            printf("%d\t", message->data[i]);
        }
    } else {
        printf("Failed to receive message\n");
    }
}

void app_main()
{
    
    twai_setup_and_install();
    twai_message_t message;
    twai_message_t message1;
    // Set the data to send
    uint8_t data[8] = {rand() % 255, rand() % 255, rand() % 255, 
    rand() % 255, rand() % 255, rand() % 255, rand() % 255, rand() % 255};

    while(true){ 
    // Create a new message
    new_message(&message, 0x123, 8, data);

    // Transmit the message to a queue
    transmit_message(&message);

    // Receive the message from the queue
    receive_message(&message1);

    // Wait for 1 second
    vTaskDelay(1000 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
    }

}
```

If anyone can help me as soon as possible, it would be really appreciated.

Sincere Regards.

Steps followed:

- I used ESP-IDF v5.0 with VS Code.
- I used the documentation to obtain the code for sender and receiver.
- I used a tested and functional MCP2515 module as my transceiver for the same.
- The Tx is broadcasting perfectly, but the Rx is not working for the above code.

Expected Output:

```
Message received:
ID: 0x123 DLC: 8 Data: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
In my source code, I have implemented random data bits, so data may vary
```

Actual Output:

```
Failed to receive message
```

Comment: "I used tool x and library y" etc is not useful when it comes to troubleshooting. You need to measure the signals on the bus and on the CAN transceiver with an oscilloscope. And watch the bus traffic using a CAN listener. From there you can narrow down the problem. If you don't have these tools, you can't develop CAN applications.

Comment: @Lundin I have used a multimeter to test the voltage changes when I am transmitting data. Therefore, the issue is with the software driver.

Comment: You can't use a multimeter. How do you know if the voltage change is because of valid data or error frames?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the twai driver for the Twai controller on the ESP32, for the MCP2515 , you need the use the MCP_CAN library to receive messages over the SPI bus to the ESP32.